# MySQL - search for a word in a text field, display whole line?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm searching for a certain word:

```
$sql = "select a, b from lala where dudu=1 and b LIKE \"%".$str."%\"";
```

This works just fine. Now I want to display the whole line where $str was found, or more lines for that matter. 
How can I do that?

'b' in this case is a column of type text and contains let's say more than 100 lines.
For instance:

```
This is some random text, I want
to perform a search on it. 
It has only three lines.
```

My $str could be "random", and I wanna get the whole line, so in this case 
    "This is some random text, I want"

Comment: Can you define "line" for us please?

Comment: Are you talking about looping through the results and showing the information returned from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what I must do. When going through results, I need another loop for getting the actual lines into php variables.

Thanks for all answers anyway.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $hostname = $row["hostname"]; 
    $config = $row["config"];

            # searching through $config separately with foreach 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This horrible looking piece of SQL will get the **first** line with an occurrence of `$search` on it, assuming the lines are new-line seperated:

```
$search = 'random'; // Sanitize me!

$sql = "
  SELECT a,
  SUBSTR(
    b,
    IF(
      LOCATE('\n', REVERSE(b), LENGTH(b) - LOCATE('".$search."', b)) > 0,
      LENGTH(b) - LOCATE('\n', REVERSE(b), LENGTH(b) - LOCATE('".$search."', b)),
      1
    ),
    IF(
      LOCATE('\n', b, LOCATE('".$search."', b)) > 0,
      LOCATE('\n', b, LOCATE('".$search."', b)) - IF(
        LOCATE('\n', REVERSE(b), LENGTH(b) - LOCATE('".$search."', b)) > 0,
        LENGTH(b) - LOCATE('\n', REVERSE(b), LENGTH(b) - LOCATE('".$search."', b)),
        1
      ),
      LENGTH(b)
    )
  ) AS line
  FROM lala
  WHERE
    dudu = 1
    AND b LIKE '%".$search."%'
";
```

I can't say that I recommend it though, I suspect it will be slooooooow.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i found a better solution in my opinion though.